# Future Simulation with External Regressions using simulate.Arima()

Tags: r, forecasting

My question involves the `simulate.Arima()` function in the forecasting.  I have an ARIMA function with seasonality, a nonzero degree of differencing, and external regressors (dummy variables for holidays).  Here is a reproducible example:

```
y <- ts(c(3,5,10,13,4,15,13,17,20,24,26,27))
dummy <- data.frame(dummy=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
arima.1 <- arima(y, order=c(1,1,0), xreg=dummy)

future.dummy <- data.frame(dummy=c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
n <- nrow(future.dummy)

sim.1 <- simulate(arima.1, nsim=n, xreg=future.dummy)
```

When I perform this, I get an error message.  I noticed that when I set the parameter `future=FALSE` it works perfectly fine.

My question: Does simulate.Arima not allow you to run a future simulation with new external regressors?  In other words, do you have to choose between

1. forecasting the future with no external regressors or
2. simulating non-future data with different external regressors?

And if this is the case, is it feasible to develop a workaround running a `simulate()` on a `predict.Arima` object?  I have a nonzero degree of differencing, so it's important that I be able to look in the future. Thanks for any insight that can be provided.

Answer (score 1):

I think I traced down the problem, so I guess I'll go ahead and answer my own question.  There is a slight difference in just what exactly is outputed by `arima` and by the `auto.arima` (from the forecast package).  A simple `names` call on an object of each type reveals the difference.

```
names(arima.1)
[1] "coef"      "sigma2"    "var.coef"  "mask"      "loglik"    "aic"      
[7] "arma"      "residuals" "call"      "series"    "code"      "n.cond"   
[13] "model"

names(auto.arima.1)
[1] "coef"      "sigma2"    "var.coef"  "mask"      "loglik"    "aic"      
[7] "arma"      "residuals" "call"      "series"    "code"      "n.cond"   
[13] "model"     "bic"       "aicc"      "xreg"      "x"
```

Notice that `auto.arima` has a few extra names, most notably the original data (`$x`) and the external regressors (`$xreg`).  So this creates problems when you feed an Arima object built by `arima` into `simulate.Arima`.  The code behind `simulate.Arima` seems to deal properly with the `$x` discrepancy, but it fails with `$xreg`.  So when you input an Arima object built by `arima`, the function code tries to reference `object$xreg`, but there is no such name attached to that object, so it just returns `NULL`.  So when the function tries to do something with `object$xreg`, it's dealing with NULL, not a data frame consisting of your external regressors. And the function breaks down at the line:

```
object$xreg <- cbind(intercept = rep(1, n), object$xreg)
```

I also notice that on the help page for `auto.arima`, under the Value section, it simple says "Same as for arima."  And while it is true that `auto.arima` outputs an Arima object, the names attached to that object are slightly different.

So in short, an Arima object with external regressors built from `auto.arima` works perfectly fine in `simulate` because it has the `$xreg` component.  It only breaks down for Arima objects built by `arima`.

Does anyone know a way to get the `xreg` parameter information from an object built out of `arima` that does not have an `xreg` name attached to it?

Comment: Use the `Arima()` function instead of `arima()` and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Big fan, by the way. Always cool to get your question answered by the author of the function himself. This seems like such an easy mistake to make. Might you consider adding a simple one line caveat on the `simulate()` help page?